# how remove the text box one bye one in button click

Tags: javascript, jquery

**HTML**

```
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


  <img id="plusicondiv" class="plusicon" src="vectorimages/pluseicon.svg" />


  <div id="plusicondivbox"class="insidediv " style="margin-top:-53px;" >

  <img class="mynasicondiv" src="vectorimages/mynas.svg" />
```

**JS**

```
$(function () {
    $('.plusicon').on('click', function () {

        var textBox = '<input type="text" class="textbox"/>';
        var a = $(this).attr("id")

        $('#'+a+"box").append(textBox);


        var img = '<img class="mynasicondiv" src="vectorimages/mynas.svg"></img>';

        $('#' + a + "box").append(img);



        $(function () {
            $(document).on("click", ".mynasicondiv", function () {
                $(this).parent('#' + a + "box").empty();
                return
            })

    });
});
```

I have two buttons, `plusicon` button and `mynesicon` button. I want click the `plusicon` button add the textbox and image,also clicking the `mynessicon` button should remove the textboxs and images. My problem is that clicking the `mynesicon` corresponding textbox is only removing.

Comment: Provide your html so that some can answer your question

Comment: Change this `$(this).parent('#' + a + "box").empty();` to `$(this).parent('#' + a + "box").remove();`

Comment: @Sherlock its not working still problem exisit

Comment: @aswathy post your html

Comment: please refer it from here http://fiddle.jshell.net/skarthik/qvtL6qf2/?utm_source=website&utm_medium=embed&utm_campaign=qvtL6qf2

Answer (score 0):

Use `.each` to remove all the elements and in order to remove use the `.remove` function on the targeted element.

```js
$(function () {
   var a;
    $('.plusicon').on('click', function () {
        
        var textBox = '<input type="text" class="textbox"/>';
        a = $(this).attr("id")
        console.log(a);
        $('#'+a+"box").append(textBox);
        
        
        var img = '<img class="mynasicondiv" src="vectorimages/mynas.svg"></img>';

        $('#' + a + "box").append(img);
       
  
    });
      $('.mynasicondiv').on("click", function () {
            $('#' + a + "box").each(function(index, v){
              $(v).remove();
            });
        });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>

<div><img id="plusicondiv" class="plusicon" src="vectorimages/pluseicon.svg" /></div>
         


              
<div><img class="mynasicondiv" src="vectorimages/mynas.svg" /> </div>

<div id="plusicondivbox"class="insidediv " ></div>
</div>
```